# C# Sockets connection confusion

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, connection

I'm just wondering about the following behavior of sockets in C#.
Normally TCP is responsible for transportation stuff including terminate a connection if requested.
And so I don't understand, why this example code has these results.
I expected that if s2 closes the connection to s3, s3 is not abled to send more data. But the s3.send(...)-Call produces no error (as you can see below).
Further I expect that server/client-role has no influence on this behavior, because the closing socket should send FIN and get back FIN/ACK anyway, so both sockets should know about the closed connection.

So please have a look at this example code:

```cs
    void MyMethod()
    {
        IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Loopback;

        Socket s1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Socket s2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        s1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localIP, 20003));
        s1.Listen(1);
        s2.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localIP, 20004));
        s2.ConnectAsync(new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIP, 20003) });
        Socket s3 = s1.Accept();

        Console.WriteLine($"Accepted Connection: {s3.LocalEndPoint} -> {s3.RemoteEndPoint}");

        s1.Close();

        Console.WriteLine($"S2: Connected: {s2.Connected} @ {s2.LocalEndPoint} -> {s2.RemoteEndPoint}");
        Console.WriteLine($"S3: Connected: {s3.Connected} @ {s3.LocalEndPoint} -> {s3.RemoteEndPoint}");
        s2.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        s2.Close();

        SocketError error;
        s3.Send(new byte[] {1, 2, 3}, 0, 3, SocketFlags.None, out error);
        Console.WriteLine($"Transmission SocketError: {error}");
        Console.WriteLine($"S2: Connected: {s2.Connected}");
        Console.WriteLine($"S3: Connected: {s3.Connected} @ {s3.LocalEndPoint} -> {s3.RemoteEndPoint}");

        s3.Close();
    }
```

This code produces this output:

```
Accepted Connection: 127.0.0.1:20003 -> 127.0.0.1:20004
S2: Connected: True @ 127.0.0.1:20004 -> 127.0.0.1:20003
S3: Connected: True @ 127.0.0.1:20003 -> 127.0.0.1:20004
Transmission SocketError: Success
S2: Connected: False
S3: Connected: True @ 127.0.0.1:20003 -> 127.0.0.1:20004
```

Comment: What were your expectations regarding the application's output? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry for that. I expected that both sockets are unconnected and the SocketError will not be Success after the transmission.

Comment: Clients are master and servers are slaves.  The server should never open or close a connection.  The server starts first as a listener.  The client opens the connections and later closes connection.  You have the server closing the connection but the socket that was created when the client opened the connection is still open.

Comment: @jdweng: I tried it the other way around, so I called s3.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) and the result is unfortunately equal.

Comment: @Atilla1899 - `I called s3.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) and the result is unfortunately equal.` ----> When did you call s3.Shutdown? And, what do you expect? Add the relevant information by editing the question.

Comment: I edited the question. After some contemplation I think that the client/server-roles should not influence the behavior at the TCP-connecion (see original post). So it should be unimportant whether I close s2 or s3.